# SVG <textPath> not showing up (with ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I'm not able to make my `<textPath>` follows my SVG path. I see in the console that this one is at 0x0 but I'm not able to change it. I also have a `font-size: 4vw` to my `#svg_text` so I really don't know what's going on.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
return(
        <div key={i*3} id="svg_container">
        <svg
        viewBox="0 0 1532.82 818.45"
        id="svg">
          <path d="M1716,795.37C1392.31,283.32,716.07,130.88,204,454.54"
          transform="translate(-203.18 -283.05)"
          fill="transparent" stroke="#000"/>

          <text id="svg_text">
            <textPath xlinkHref="#curve">
              this is a test - this is a test
            </textPath>
          </text>
          </svg>
        </div>
      )
    }   })
```

---

Here's my CSS code:

```
#svg_container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#svg {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
}


#svg_text{
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-family: Dia-Bold;
  color: white;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is defined `#curve`? Once the `id` is added to your `<path>`, it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/c1ghum60/ VTC as typo?

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, that was the error.

Comment: Then do not accept the other answer if it didn't help you solve your issue. Such questions, caused by typographical error (and we all make these), should get deleted since they won't help future readers.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because your code it not online and this works too (although i'm not sure its best practice). But its not a typo error its adding the `id` to the `<path>` as well.

Comment: No, their answer did not talk at all about this only error you made, and no, it won't work either. If you don't accept it being a typo and sincerely think this may help someone in the future (though you'd have to explain me how they will stumble on your Q/A), then please self-answer, but by all means, do not accept an answer that do not solve your issue, this sends a wrong message to hypothetical future readers (even though here, I doubt there will be many)...

Comment: @cyruslk Have you tried given answer? Please accept the answer if the answer resolves your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Looks like textPath is not supported in React so what you can do is

```
   const  textPath = `<textPath xlinkHref="#curve">
          this is a test - this is a test
        </textPath>`;

        <text id="svg_text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: textPath }}></text>
```

add xmlns for svg and xlink at root svg element like below

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1532.82 818.45" id="svg">
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not a valid ReactJS syntax. My console says: Syntax error: Namespace tags are not supported. ReactJSX is not XML.

Comment: Hey thanks for correcting me. My bad. Looks like textPath not supporting in React can you try my updated answer once